# How to find duplicate phrases in a large string

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I am trying to figure out an efficient way to find duplicate phrases in a large string. The string will contain hundreds or thousands of words separated by an empty space. I've included code below that I am currently using but it is very inefficient in finding duplicate phrases.

```
    public static string FindDuplicateSubstringFast(string s, string keyword, bool allowOverlap = true)
{
    int matchPos = 0, maxLength = 0;
    if (s.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()))
        for (int shift = 1; shift < s.Length; shift++)
        {
            int matchCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length - shift; i++)
            {

                if (s[i] == s[i + shift])
                {
                    matchCount++;
                    if (matchCount > maxLength)
                    {
                        maxLength = matchCount;
                        matchPos = i - matchCount + 1;
                    }
                    if (!allowOverlap && (matchCount == shift))
                    {
                        // we have found the largest allowable match 
                        // for this shift.
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else matchCount = 0;
            }
        }
    string newbs = s.Substring(matchPos, maxLength);
    if (maxLength > 3) return s.Substring(matchPos, maxLength);
    else return null;
}
```

I found the example code above @ [Find duplicate content in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223554/find-duplicate-content-in-string)

This method is going through every char and I would like to find a way to loop through each word. I'm not sure what would be the best way to do this. I was thinking I could split the string on the empty spaces and then put the words into a list. Iterating through a list should be way more efficient than iterating over every char like I am doing now. However, I don't know how I would iterate through the list and find duplicate phrases.

If anyone could help me figure out an algorithm to iterate through a list to find duplicate phrases, I would be very grateful. I would also be open to any other ideas or methods to find duplicate phrases within a large string.

Please let me know if any more info is needed.

**EDIT:**
Here is an example of a large string {its small for this example}

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry.  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
>   ever since the 1500s.

For example sake "Lorem Ipsum" would be the duplicate phrase. I need to return "Lorem Ipsum" and any other duplicate phrases that appear in the string more than once.

Comment: You might find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton useful. There are links there for other datastructures that could also do you well.

Comment: Otherwise you could just split the string into words with split(), and then add each word to a hashmap<String, Integer> (I'm more used to java so I can't recall what C#'s version of that is called). Then loop through your hashmap and pull out any key with a value greater than 1.

Comment: 'Dictionary' is the .Net equivalent of Java's 'HashMap'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string[] split = BigString.Split(' ').ToLower();
var duplicates = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int i = 0;i<split.Length;i++)
{
    int j=i;
    string s = split[i] + " ";
    while(i+j<split.Length)
    {
        j++;
        s += split[j] + " ";
        if (Regex.Matches(BigString.ToLower(), s).Count ==1) break;
        duplicates[s] = Regex.Matches(BigString.ToLower(), s).Count;
    }
}
```

Now, the dictionary will contain all the phrases and "subphrases" e.g. "Lorem Ipsum Dolor" will find "Lorem Ipsum" and "Lorem Ipsum Dolor". If that's not interesting to you, it's just a matter of looping through the `Keys` Collection of `duplicates`. If one key is a substring of another key, and their value is the same, remove said key.

Comment: I update my post to show a small example of a string with a duplicate phrase in it. A phrase is not delimited within the string.

Comment: I had to make a few small tweaks but this did the trick. Thank You!