# How to find a pattern of words in a list c#

Tags: c#, winforms, full-text-search

I have been trying to create an application where we can find patterns in a file(txt). I do know how to get the pattern by giving specific words and finding out how many times that word has been repeated.
What I am trying to get is patterns which are not specific, more like finding a pattern without an input of words for searching.

For example

1. John is working at home and [is using a] mac. [He stays in] Chicago.
2. The customer [is using a] phone for ordering groceries. [He stays in] India.
3. [He stays in] LA, who [is using a] Fake account to access a website.

Here when I get the above lines in a file I am not aware of what is present in the file and what I have to search but I want to get the reputative patterns which are "is using a" and "He stays in" as output.

Apologies if I am not clear with my explanation. It will be of great help if someone could help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to match grammatical parts rather than specific strings?

Comment: Do you have a min length for sub strings? Are they required to be found in *all* input strings?

Comment: @bcg Its like I am making an application where we can find some sentences for insight generation. Yeah it is more like grammatical parts which are not confined. It can be anything. The sentence "item is used" can be present in the whole data in all the lines. but I don't know what i want to find. If i get an output that "item is used" is a reputative pattern, I can analyze on the word "item is used" and work on it

Comment: I wonder if you could do this by having a list of valid first words (in this case `string[] { "he", "is" }` etc and matching those - if there is a match, get the next word and match against valid strings (e.g. `string[] { "using", "stays" }`) and then the third.  If it needs to be more generic than that then to be honest I'm not sure how you could do it without using ML and teaching it to understand sentence construction!

Comment: @JonasH No. I don't have a min length. They are required to be found in all input strings without any specific length. To be more precise let's assume all the lines have "My name is Ishaq" included in them for different complaints. after getting the output that "My name is Ishaq" I can find out that the Ishaq is the one who is always commenting in the data and find out his reason why is he commenting so many times for different items.

Comment: A regular expression would work well for the 'my name is xxx' example.  You could have a list of common (i.e. fixed) regular expressions and use those to match the key phrases and pick up the next word?  For example, "my name is (\w+)" or "is using a (\w+)" would match the key phrase and return the next word.

Comment: @bcg I do understand that it needs ML to do this kind of stuff but I guess there can be a loophole to just read the specific words that are being repeated without mentioning the searched words like combing few words that are repeated?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find duplicate phrases in a large string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072371/how-to-find-duplicate-phrases-in-a-large-string)

Comment: @Rekshino No, in this we have to give the search pattern which I don't want to provide. As I said in my question, I will be not aware of the keywords I want to search.

Comment: Where have you found a given pattern?? All duplicates will be found there as I can see.

Comment: @Rekshino Sorry my bad. That is exactly what I needed but here I am facing one issue while finding a pattern when given the string as 
string BigString = "Item is used, item was is used, chocolate is good, is good";
I am just getting "is used" as the output and not "is good" because of the comma and full stop differences. I tried separating it with the comma symbol in the array but it is not working. I want is used and is good despite of the comma or full stop in the sentence as we cannot predict the symbols.

Comment: @Rekshino For being precise, "chocolate is good, myname is good";
this string is returning 0. It should give the output as "is good"

Comment: Remove all commas and other unnecessary symbols ..

Comment: @Rekshino I tried that. I even tried for this string ""chocolate was good ite asas asdasd was good" still getting 0 as output. Where actually I should get "was good" as output

Comment: Have you tried to add blank to the end of string?

Comment: @Rekshino Yes. Still not working

Comment: I become one entry for "was good" with number occurrences of 2. Check your code, if it doesn't work post new question.

Comment: No It is showing 0. I will try to post a new question as you said. Thank you very much for the start @Rekshino :)